# Django/Djagno REST field lookup "range" does not return a range, but rather single value results

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to return a range of objects containing date attributes. Using the field lookup [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#range), it only returns objects with the start range.

For example:

If start of the range is equal to 2021-05-19 and end of the range is equal to 2021-05-21, only objects with the date 2021-05-19 are being returned.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('weekly/<str:activity_date>/', views.ActivityDateList.as_view(), name='weekly_dates'),
    ...
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import ActivityListSerializer
from .models import Activity
from keeper import serializers
...

class WeeklyActivityView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ActivityListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        end_of_week = "2021-05-21" # Temporary test date
        activity_date = self.kwargs['activity_date']

        return render(Activity.objects.filter(activity_date__range=(activity_date, end_of_week)))
```

models.py

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    activity_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    activity_duration = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    activity_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Activity: {self.activity_name} Started at: {self.activity_start} Activity Duration: {self.activity_duration}"
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Activity
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

class ActivityListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    absolute_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = [
            'activity_name',
            'activity_duration',
            'activity_date',
            'absolute_url'
        ]

    def get_absolute_url(self, obj):
        return reverse('activities_detail', args=(obj.pk,))
```

Only single dates are being returned:
[image: Output]

Objects with other dates exist:

[image: Other objects]

How can I return objects with date attributes within the range specified?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Being blind, in *urls.p*y I passed:
`views.ActivityDateList.as_view()`
instead of `views.WeeklyActivityView.as_view()`.

Also, I used render, however there is no template to be rendered, therefore a "template does not exist" error would should up. The correct idea was to omit render()

Answer (score 0):

in the code inorder to use date add __date to field

`return render(Activity.objects.filter(activity_date__range=(activity_date, end_of_week)))`

replace with

`return render(Activity.objects.filter(activity_date__date__range=(activity_date, end_of_week)))`